# How to retain date format when saving to Mongo DB using Java drivers?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I have a json string

```
{
"expireDate":"2018-10-02",
"cancelDate":"2018-12-09"
}
```

but when I save this Json into mongo using Document.parse as

```
Document document=Document.parse(json);

documentCollection.insertOne(document)
```

The document in mongo stores it as

```
{
expiryDate : 2018-10-02T:00:00:00.000+00:00,
cancelDate : 2018-12-09T:00:00:00.000+00.00
}
```

I dont want mongo to add time to my dates and just want it to store date as

```
{
expireDate:2018-10-02,
cancelDate:2018-12-09
}
```

in mongo db

Comment: That is how [Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date) is stored in MongoDB database. If you want to store date just as "yyyy-MMM-dd" format,then you can store it as a string.

Comment: I am passing it as a string but when saving it to mongo its auto converting it? How do I specify the format and where?